# By adding a bilinear constraint in the form $x^T A y=0$, is this problem still convex-concave?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have a function $f(x,y)$ which is convex with respect to $x$ and concave to $y$. The problem 
\begin{align}
\min_x \max_y f(x,y)\\
\text{s.t.} x \in \mathcal{C}
\end{align} 
is then convex-concave saddle point. Now I found that I have to add another constraint in the form $x^\mathsf{T}A y=0$, where $A$ is an invertible matrix. Is the following problem still convex-concave?
\begin{align}
\min_x & \max_y f(x,y)\\
\text{s.t.} &x\in \mathcal{C}\\
&x^\mathsf{T} A y = 0
\end{align} 
I know that a problem of the form 
\begin{align}
\min_x & \max_y x^\mathsf{T} A y\\
\text{s.t.} &x\in \mathcal{C}\\
\end{align}
is convex-concave.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "convex-conave"?  In the well studied subject of convex-concave games, you can have linear (in)equalities involving $x$ and separate (in)equalities involving $y$ but not equilibrium constraints involving both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: This is a saddle point problem in machine learning. As said it is convex with respect to one variable and concave with respect to another. This problem is not coming from a game. Can't we reach to an equivalent problem by adding the constraint to objective?

Comment: My point was simply that the problem you've stated doesn't fit into the standard theory.

Comment: What is the definition of "convex-concave" problem ? How do constraints incorporate play role in definition of a "convex-concave" problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have the *bilinear* equation

$$\rm x^{\top} A \, y = 0$$

where $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is a given invertible matrix. The equation above can be rewritten as follows

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x\\ \mathrm y\end{bmatrix}^{\top} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm O_n & \mathrm A\\ \,\mathrm A^{\top} & \,\mathrm O_n\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x\\ \mathrm y\end{bmatrix} = 0$$

The characteristic polynomial of the block matrix is

$$\det \begin{bmatrix} s \mathrm I_n & -\mathrm A\\ -\mathrm A^{\top} & s\mathrm I_n\end{bmatrix} = \det \left( s^2 \mathrm I_n - \mathrm A \mathrm A^{\top} \right)$$

Since $\mathrm A$ is invertible, $\mathrm A \mathrm A^{\top}$ is positive definite. Thus, the spectrum of the block matrix contains the positive and negative square roots of the positive eigenvalues of $\mathrm A \mathrm A^{\top}$. Hence,

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm O_n & \mathrm A\\ \,\mathrm A^{\top} & \,\mathrm O_n\end{bmatrix}$$

is **indefinite**. We then conclude that the set

$$\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x\\ \mathrm y\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{2n} : \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x\\ \mathrm y\end{bmatrix}^{\top} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm O_n & \mathrm A\\ \,\mathrm A^{\top} & \,\mathrm O_n\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x\\ \mathrm y\end{bmatrix} = 0 \right\}$$

is **non-convex**.

Comment: Thank you very much. Simple and elegant. Do you have any hint for me on how to  approximate it with a convex set?

Comment: @user85361 Let $n=1$ and $A = 1$. Then $x y = 0$ implies $x = 0 \lor y = 0$, i.e., the set defined by $x y = 0$ is the *union* of the two axes, which is clearly non-convex. I do not see in what sense one can approximate the set.

Answer (score 1):

A standard approach can be used to convert your program into a single level optimization problem.

Start with

$\min_{x} \max_{y} f(x,y)$

subject to

$x \in C$

$x^{T}Ay=0$.

Now, assuming that the Karush-Kuhn Tucker sufficient conditions for the inner maximization are satisfied, we can substitute them into the problem.  For any given $x$, the KKT conditions for the inner maximization are:

$\nabla_{y} f(x,y)=\lambda A^{T}x $

$x^{T}Ay=0$.

The original problem can then be written as:

$\min_{x,y,\lambda} f(x,y)$

subject to

$x \in C$

$x^{T}Ay=0$

$\nabla_{y} f(x,y)=\lambda A^{T}x $.

Whether you can solve this will depend on the details of $f$ but it won't be a convex problem.

Comment: Thank you Brian. So, do you mean the problem is not convex-concave?