# Add some constraints to make $x^TAy \geq 0$ where $A \succ 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, bilinear-form

I am trying to prove the difference of two algorithms' asymptotic mean square error. Eventually, I get an expression like $x^TAy$, where $A$ is a positive definite matrix. I would love to see under which conditions one algorithm can "beat the other", i.e., I am looking for the $\mathcal D \subset \Bbb R^p \times \Bbb R^p$ such that

$$\left( \forall (x,y) \in \mathcal D \right) \left( x^T A y \ge 0 \right)$$

where $x, y \in \Bbb R^p$ and $p \gg 2$. For example, if we treat it as a constrained optimization problem

$$S := \min x^TAy$$

subject to "some constraints", then $S=0$. What constraints can I put here? Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2261932/339790).

Comment: Think of the 1-dimensional case $xy \geq 0$.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that. I'll edit the problem :)

Comment: Diagonalizing $A$ may help, especially if it's symmetric.

Comment: Alternatively, if $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, there exists invertible $B$ with $A = B^TB$. In particular, if $A = R\Lambda R^T$ for orthogonal $R$, then $B = \Lambda^{1/2}R^T$. The condition becomes $(Bx)^T(By) \ge 0$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog If it is PD, it's symmetric.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you for making this post neat. I appreciate it!

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo That's a matter of definition. Some authors only require $x^⊤ A x>0$ for $x≠0$ for a matrix to be PD, which does not imply that $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: @Hyperplane Yes, but how does that definition make any sense?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo How does it not make sense? In fact, it seems quite "natural" to me. It is equivalent to multiple statements about the homogeneous quadratic function $Q(x)= x^⊤Ax$, which is **the** direct generalization of the scalar function $x↦αx^2$: (1) $\{x∣Q(x)>0\}$ is maximal. (2) $Q$ is strictly convex (3) $\{x∣Q(x)=0\}=\{0\}$ 

In fact, adding the symmetry assumption as a requirement seems kind of artificial to be honest, when the property can simply be extended to all square matrices.

Comment: @Hyperplane Because the *skew*-symmetric part contributes nothing to the quadratic form. Hence, it makes more sense to me to consider the symmetric part only. Some consider positive definiteness to be a property of quadratic forms and the associated matrix that is called positive definite is the symmetric one.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Well, I guess what I want to point out is that there are multiple definitions and that on a public board like this it is best to not assume what definition other people are following. We can compensate that by being more explicit (e.g. saying *"SPD matrix"* instead of *"PD matrix"*).

I'm sure debates about whatever definition is best could go on forever, but note that for example here in Germany quite a few of the standard undergraduate texts define positive definiteness without the symmetry assumption. (In fact, even the German Wikipedia differs from the English one!)