# Scalar form with a negative definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

Given a real $n\times n$ matrix $A$ that is symmetric and negative definite. I am interested in the properties of the bilinear form associated with this matrix.

Specifically, could it ever be possible to choose two positive, real vectors $x, y\in \mathbb{R}^n_+$ such that $x^\top A y \geq 0$?

Clearly this would not be true for the quadratic form $x^\top A x$, since negative definiteness would imply that $x^\top A x < 0$ for all $x$.

But would it be possible, for example, to construct a negative definite matrix whose bilinear form is only negative when $x=y$ (or for $x$ in a small region around $y$?)

Comment: By a coordinate transformation, you may assume the matrix is diagonal with negative entries. That should make the problem a lot simpler.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. Say I were to take the eigenvalue decomposition of $A$ as $A = Q^\top \Lambda Q$ where $\Lambda$ is diagonal with negative entries and $Q^\top Q$ = $Q Q^\top = I$. Then I could write $x^\top A y = \bar{x}^\top \Lambda \bar{y}$ where $\bar{v}=Qv$. Is it possible for an orthogonal matrix $Q$ and positive vectors $x$ and $y$ to have $\bar{x}_i$ positive and $\bar{y}_i$ negative?

Comment: Right, the vectors were supposed to be positive too. Didn't notice that.

Comment: You can make a negative definite $A$ where also all entries are strictly negative, so $x^TAy$ will be strictly negative for all positive vectors $x,y$.

Comment: Why should $\bf A$ be symmetric?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo A is symmetric for my specific application

Comment: @phil Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2261932/339790)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo That link contains the answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the matrix
$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &0 \\
0& -1
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$x=(-1,-1),y=(1,1), \langle Ax,y \rangle>0 $$
But if your matrix is written in diagonal form and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}$, then $$\langle Ax,y \rangle \leq 0$$ But if it is not in diagonal form, then there  are counterxamples:
$$B=
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 &\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{3}} \\
\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{3}} & -1-\frac{1}{3}
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\langle B(1,1),(1,1) \rangle \leq 0 $$ $$\langle B(0.001,1),(1,0.001)\rangle > 0$$ So in order to prevent such counterexamples , $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}$ shcould be replaced by the half space consisiting of positive linear combinations of eigenvectors of $A$.
Concerning your second question:the map $(x,y)\to \langle Ax,y \rangle$ is continous , if it is negative on the diagonal ($x=y$),then it would be negative in a neighborhood of the diagonal.Remark that if $\langle Ax,y \rangle >0 \implies \langle Ax,-y \rangle <0 $,so the region where the bilinear form is negative is as large as the region where it is positive (the map $(x,y)\to (x,-y)$ is an isometry).

Comment: Thank you! Just to make sure (I worked through it my hand so I am pretty sure,) do you mean that $\langle B(1,1), (1,10)\rangle \geq 0$?

Comment: Also, in this example the matrix $B$ is not negative definite?

Comment: @phil thank you for pointing out that $B$ is not negative definite, I edited my answer

Comment: Thank you. I think your answer is correct but I am still having trouble with the counterexample. Now the matrix $B$ is indeed negative definite, but for a counterexample, shouldn't $\langle Bx, y\rangle$ be $> 0$?

Comment: I just played around in Julia a bit and the counterexample does work with $x=(0.001,1)$ and $y = (1,0.001)$

Comment: @phil I'm Sorry I didn't pay attention that we need the other inequality,though u mentionned it in your comment.

Comment: No problem, I just edited the answer to add the counterexample so that I can accept the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @phil you are welcome